# Controlling azure worker roles concurrency in multiple instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-worker-roles

I have a simple work role in azure that does some data processing on an SQL azure database.
The worker basically adds data from a 3rd party datasource to my database every 2 minutes. When I have two instances of the role, this obviously doubles up unnecessarily. I would like to have 2 instances for redundancy and the 99.95 uptime, but do not want them both processing at the same time as they will just duplicate the same job. Is there a standard pattern for this that I am missing?
I know I could set flags in the database, but am hoping there is another easier or better way to manage this.
Thanks

Comment: Well, you could put a trigger message on an Azure queue, because only one client can read a message at a time. However, this just raises the question of how to create those messages in the first place. If you do that from Worker Roles at scheduled intervals, you have the same problem once more because each concurrent Worker Role is going to send the same message at approximately the same time. I can't think of a solution to this that doesn't involve a semaphore of some kind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Mark suggested, you can use an Azure queue to post a message. You can have the worker role instance post a followup message to the queue as the last thing it does when processing the current message. That should deal with the issue Mark brought up regarding the need for a semaphore. In your queue message, you can embed a timestamp marking when the message can be processed. When creating a new message, just add two minutes to current time.

And... in case it's not obvious: in the event the worker role instance crashes before completing processing and fails to repost a new queue message, that's fine. In this case, the current queue message will simply reappear on the queue and another instance is then free to process it.

Comment: Make sure that you implement a poison message filter, though: if a worker role is crashing because of that particular message, you do not want to have it reposted to the queue over and over. A repost count (or read count) can help you there.

Comment: How do you start this perpetual machine? If you have two instances of a role starting at the same time which one should post the 1st message?

Comment: I'm using queues with duplicate detection through the Service Bus to ensure that only one instance performs an action. All worker roles sends a message on startup with the same MessageId. The ServiceBus then suppresses all messages except one wich is delivered to one of the instances. http://www.cloudcasts.net/devguide/Default.aspx?id=13026

Answer (score 0):

There is not a super easy way to do this, I dont think.

You can use a semaphore as Mark has mentioned, to basically record the start and the stop of processing.  Then you can have any amount of instances running, each inspecting the semaphore record and only acting out if semaphore allows it.

However, the caveat here is that what happens if one of the instances crashes in the middle of processing and never releases the semaphore?  You can implement a "timeout" value after which other instances will attempt to kick-start processing if there hasnt been an unlock for X amount of time.

Alternatively, you can use a third party monitoring service like [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) to watch for unresponsive instances in Azure and start a new instance if the amount of "Ready" instances is under 1.  This will save you can save some money by not having to have 2 instances up and running all the time, but there is a slight lag between when an instance fails and when a new one is started.

Answer (score 0):

A Semaphor as suggested would be the way to go, although I'd probably go with a simple timestamp heartbeat in blob store.

The other thought is, how necessary is it? If your loads can sustain being down for a few minutes, maybe just let the role recycle?

Answer (score 0):

Small catch on David's solution. Re-posting the message to the queue would happen as the last thing on the current execution so that if the machine crashes along the way the current message would expire and re-surface on the queue. That assumes that the message was originally peeked and requires a de-queue operation to remove from the queue. The de-queue must happen before inserting the new message to the queue. If the role crashes in between these 2 operations, then there will be no tokens left in the system and will come to a halt.
The ESB dup check sounds like a feasible approach, but it does not sound like it would be deterministic either since the bus can only check for identical messages currently existing in a queue. But if one of the messages comes in right after the previous one was de-queued, there is a chance to end up with 2 processes running in parallel.

An alternative solution, if you can afford it, would be to never de-queue and just lease the message via Peek operations. You would have to ensure that the invisibility timeout never goes beyond the processing time in your worker role. As far as creating the token in the first place, the same worker role startup strategy described before combined with ASB dup check should work (since messages would never move from the queue).